# Fill missing values by group, but don't carry over

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following table:

| ID | Date | Compensation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 004 | Jan1 | NA |
| 004 | Jan2 | 55 |
| 004 | Jan6 | NA |
| 010 | Dec12 | NA |
| 010 | Dec14 | NA |
| 010 | Dec15 | 66 |
| 010 | Dec16 | NA |
| 012 | Feb5 | 33 |
| 012 | Feb9 | NA |
| 012 | Feb10 | NA |
| 012 | May2 | 89 |

What I basically want is to fill in the missing values within the group within having the value to then carry over to the next group. This is my code

```
DataWanted <- Data
        dplyr::group_by("ID", "Date") %>% 
fill("Compensation", .direction = "down")
```

See the table for what the compensation result I'm getting versus the one I actually want. Basically I want to fill in values by grouping IDs. So if there is no compensation for a group in the beginning, then I don't want the compensation value from previous ID copied over, just leave it as NA.

| ID | Date | Compensation Column Getting | Compensation Column I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 004 | Jan1 | NA | NA |
| 004 | Jan2 | 55 | 55 |
| 004 | Jan6 | 55 | 55 |
| 010 | Dec 12 | 55 | NA |
| 010 | Dec14 | 55 | NA |
| 010 | Dec15 | 66 | 66 |
| 010 | Dec16 | 66 | 66 |
| 012 | Feb5 | 33 | 33 |
| 012 | Feb9 | 33 | 33 |
| 012 | Feb10 | 33 | 33 |
| 012 | May2 | 89 | 89 |

Comment: `data |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  fill(Compensation, .direction = "updown")`

Comment: This won't work. I want to maintain the NA if there aren't any compensation values in the beginning of the Date for each ID. only continue filling down once you encounter a number. So only going down (stop at the next ID).

Comment: And changing the `.direction` argument to "down" won't achieve that?

Comment: Nope. It keeps copying down from one group to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer because I can't demonstrate within a comment:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(~ID, ~Date, ~Compensation,
"004",  "Jan1",     NA,
"004",  "Jan2",     55,
"004",  "Jan6",     NA,
"010",  "Dec12",    NA,
"010",  "Dec14",    NA,
"010",  "Dec15",    66,
"010",  "Dec16",    NA,
"012",  "Feb5",     33,
"012",  "Feb9",     NA,
"012",  "Feb10",    NA,
"012",  "May2",     89)

data |>    
  mutate(Date = Date |> 
           str_replace("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", " ") |> 
           paste(" 2023") |> 
           mdy()) |> 
  arrange(Date) |> 
  group_by(ID) |>    
  fill(Compensation, .direction = "down") |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 11 × 3
   ID    Date       Compensation
   <chr> <date>            <dbl>
 1 004   2023-01-01           NA
 2 004   2023-01-02           55
 3 004   2023-01-06           55
 4 012   2023-02-05           33
 5 012   2023-02-09           33
 6 012   2023-02-10           33
 7 012   2023-05-02           89
 8 010   2023-12-12           NA
 9 010   2023-12-14           NA
10 010   2023-12-15           66
11 010   2023-12-16           66
```

I'm not sure why setting the `.direction` argument to "down" wouldn't work. I can't replicate your issue, or maybe I'm just not understanding the intent.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing with my data. But for whatever reason, the fill  with down option ignores the group_by and extends the last observation regardless of the grouping of ID

Comment: There must be something else going on with your data, or perhaps a difference in package version (unlikely) that would result in a difference in behaviour.

Comment: I figured it out. The group_by had the ID in brackets for some reason: group_by ("ID")...changed it to group_by (ID) and voila... Thanks for the help though!